# libc6-dev/libc-dev : "Unable to fix problems, bad packets are in “keep as is” mode."

Tags: linux, tensorflow, ubuntu, amd-gpu

first sorry, since my terminal is in french, I'll use google translate for all the outputs so the terminology may not be perfectly accurate.

I am running `Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS` and I want to use tensorflow with a `AMD® Firepro w7100` gpu. I tried to follow [this tutorial to use Tensorflow 2 & PyTorch for AMD GPUs](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/install-tensorflow-2-for-amd-gpus-87e8d7aeb812). However when I am running

> sudo apt install amdgpu-dkms

I have the following error :

```
[sudo] wlutz password:
Reading package lists... Done
Building the dependency tree
Reading status information... Done
Some packages cannot be installed. This can mean
that you have asked for the impossible, or, if you use
the unstable distribution, which some packages do not yet have
been created or not released from Incoming.
The following information should help you resolve the situation:

The following packages contain unmet dependencies:
 amdgpu-dkms: Depends: libc-dev or
                        libc6-dev but will not be installed
E: Unable to fix problems, bad packets are in "keep as is" mode.
```

And it is basically doing similar things with other packages I want to install.
Do you perhaps know something about this ?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try to fix the dependencies for the packages that are being displayed:

```
sudo apt install libc6-dev
```

If you can't install it, try to download it manually ([PKGS - Packages for Linux and Unix](https://pkgs.org/download/libc6-dev)) and install it with command:

```
sudo dpkg -i <file_name>
```

Check again if the installation for `amdgpu-dkms` is working:

```
sudo apt install amdgpu-dkms
```

If it still doesn't work, try:

```
sudo apt --fix-missing update
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -f
```

Comment: It does not work because i have other broken dependencies it seems, and I do not have the superuser permissions to fix it, so i will see with the IT services then try again your solution. thank you.